# AspectJ Pointcut to exclude annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I'm using Spring AOP for logging. I want to create a pointcut that applies to all methods except those that have a specific annotation, but I have no idea how to go about it. All I've found is how to *include* methods with an annotation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Sample annotation:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NoLogging {}
```

**Driver Application:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        foo();
        bar();
        zot();
        baz();
    }

    @NoLogging public static void foo() {}
    public static void bar() {}
    @NoLogging public static void zot() {}
    public static void baz() {}
}
```

**Aspect in native AspectJ syntax:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.NoLogging;

public aspect MyAspect {
    before() : execution(* *(..)) && !@annotation(NoLogging) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

**Aspect in @AspectJ syntax (should also work in Spring AOP):**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class MyAspectX {
    @Before("execution(* *(..)) && !@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.NoLogging)")
    public void logExceptAnnotated(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

Both aspects are equivalent and yield the following output:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.bar())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.baz())
```

Comment: Hi @kriegaex can you please help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48882522/1029634

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
execution(* my.package.*.*(..)) && !execution(@annotation * my.package.*.*(..))
```

Comment: The syntax is okay, but suboptimal (see my own answer). Please also note, that `my.package.*.*` does not include subpackages. You may want to use `my.package..*.*` instead.