# Exclude annotated methods in AspectJ

Tags: java, android, aop, aspectj

Hi I want to exclude the annotated method here is the code.

```
@Aspect
public class ExceptionHandlingAspect {
    private static final String TAG = ExceptionHandlingAspect.class.getName();

   @Pointcut("execution(* android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.*(..)) " +
        "&& !@annotation(android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.exception.NoTryCatch)")
   public void exceptionEntryPoint() {
   }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "exceptionEntryPoint()", throwing = "throwable")
    public void exceptionMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught : " + throwable + " on method : " + joinPoint.getSignature());
        if (joinPoint.getTarget() instanceof Activity) {
            if (throwable instanceof AuthenticationException) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder((Context) joinPoint.getTarget())
                        .setTitle("Authentication Error")
                        .setMessage("You are not authenticated")
                        .show();
            } else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder((Context) joinPoint.getTarget())
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("Error occurred at : " + joinPoint.getSignature() + " " +
                                "Exception : " + throwable)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Around(value = "exceptionEntryPoint()")
    public Object exceptionAroundMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Exclude any method which is annotated with `NoTryCatch`

Above code does exclude the method which annotated with NoTryCatch but when this method get called with exception it halts the execution of next methods. e.g

```
@NoTryCatch
void test(){throws NullPointor..}
```

now I call methods in sequence

```
test()
test1()
```

test1() does not run.

If I remove `!@annotation(android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.exception.NoTryCatch)` the test1() runs

Comment: This works on Android also. I don't know much about spring framework.

Comment: basically I am using `aspectj` plugin in Android.

Comment: it is possible to get the source of the joinPoint, which includes a list of annotations applied to it. I think that's your best guess.

Comment: add this as first line in your aop method: Method enclosing = new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod(); from that enclosing variable, you can get the list of annotations (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Can't we use `Pointcut` for that?

Comment: @Stultuske: Your code does not make sense, it only gets enclosing methods for anonymous classes defined within methods. @john smith: Of course you can get the intercepted method from the joinpoint, no problem. But before I answer your question, I would like to see the pointcut `notLogException()` used in your "around" advice.

Comment: Hi @kriegaex sorry forgot to remove it.

Comment: Thanks!! I want if method is annotated with @NoTryCatch then `exceptionMethod` 
 should not catch exception. Even if the method with `NoTryCatch` throws exception it should crash the app. For other normal methods `exceptionMethod` should show the alert dialog and prevent app from crashing.

Comment: @kriegaex you are right, I was thinking about MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature)jPoint.getSignature();
        Method origin = signature.getMethod();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course `test1()` does not run if you ignore the exception thrown in `test()`, i.e. let it escalate. Due to that unhandled exception the next method is never called. I thought this is exactly what your aspect is designed to do. Why are you expecting different behaviour? And if you do expect something else, then please describe it in a comment and I can show you in an edit of my answer how to do it.

---

**Update after OP's comment:**

Well, you are having a home-made problem here: If method `void caller()` calls `@NoTryCatch void callee()`, of course the exception in `callee()` will not be handled, just as designed. Instead it escalates up to `caller()` which is not annotated and thus the aspect will handle it there. How can the caller know that the exception was ignored by an aspect in the callee? Or how can the aspect know, for that matter? The callee's control flow has already ended when returning control to the caller.

This concept of exception handling is tricky at the very least. I would even call it questionable because the inner-most element of a call chain determines that all the outer elements should ignore an exception. Usually exception handling works just the other way. The caller determines how to handle an exception thrown by the callee, not the callee itself. So I advise you to change your idea and concept of exception handling.

Having said that, I will show you that what I said really happens in your application with a little [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Because I am not an Android developer and want this to run on any Java SE machine, I emulated the relevant parts of the Android API like this with mock-ups:

**Android API mock-ups:**

```java
package android.content;

public class Context {}
```

```java
package android.app;

import android.content.Context;

public class Activity extends Context {}
```

This one emulates an alert dialog by just logging to the console.

```
package android.app;

import android.content.Context;

public class AlertDialog {
  public AlertDialog() {}

  public static class Builder {
    private String title;
    private String message;

    public Builder(Context target) {}

    public Builder setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
      return this;
    }

    public void show() {
      System.out.println("ALERT DIALOG: " + title + " -> " + message);
    }
  }
}
```

```java
package org.apache.http.auth;

public class AuthenticationException extends Exception {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public AuthenticationException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.exception;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface NoTryCatch {}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid;

import org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.exception.NoTryCatch;

public class AspectActivity extends Activity {
  public String doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing something");
    return "something";
  }

  @NoTryCatch
  public String doSomethingElse() {
    System.out.println("Doing something else");
    throw new RuntimeException("oops");
  }

  public String doSomethingFancy() throws AuthenticationException {
    System.out.println("Doing something fancy");
    throw new AuthenticationException("uh-oh");
  }

  public void run() throws AuthenticationException {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
    doSomethingFancy();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws AuthenticationException {
    new AspectActivity().run();
  }
}
```

**OP's aspect, slightly optimised:**

Basically this is exactly your aspect with a few optimisations:

- You split your error handling logic into two advices, one "around" and one "after throwing". This makes it a bit hard to follow the actual control flow because in one advice you log the error, only to later catch and ignore the same error in the other advice. Thus, I decided to pull the logging into the "catch" block of the "around" advice, making it clearer what happens.
- Your original pointcut only targets methods in class `AspectActivity`. Thus, it is clear that the joinpoint's target is always an `Activity` and thus always a `Context`. Binding the `target()` to an advice parameter is clearer, more type-safe and gets you rid of ugly casts and `instanceof`.
- I split your pointcut into two because we can re-use them both later in iteration 2, see below.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity;
import android.util.Log;

@Aspect
public class ExceptionHandlingAspect {
  private static final String TAG = ExceptionHandlingAspect.class.getName();

  @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && target(activity)")
  public void methodsOfInterest(AspectActivity activity) {}

  @Pointcut("@annotation(android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.exception.NoTryCatch)")
  public void annotationNoTryCatch() {}

  @Around("methodsOfInterest(activity) && !annotationNoTryCatch()")
  public Object exceptionAroundMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, AspectActivity activity) {
    try {
      return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
      String errorMessage = "Error " + throwable + " in method " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
      Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
      Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
      if (throwable instanceof AuthenticationException)
        builder.setTitle("Authentication Error").setMessage("You are not authenticated").show();
      else
        builder.setTitle("Error").setMessage(errorMessage).show();
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
Doing something
Doing something else
[de.scrum_master.aspect.ExceptionHandlingAspect] Error java.lang.RuntimeException: oops in method void android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.run()
ALERT DIALOG: Error -> Error java.lang.RuntimeException: oops in method void android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.run()
```

The log clearly shows

- that the annotated method `doSomethingElse()` is executed and the error is not handled there,
- but that the calling method `run()` triggers the advice instead, thus the error is handled there.
- Even if you also annotate `run()`, the error would be handled in `main(..)`.

So what do you need to do in order to avoid annotating the whole call chain? There is only one - quite ugly - way of doing this: manual bookkeeping, i.e. your aspect needs to remember exception instances it has ignored before because the corresponding error-handling advice has never run for that very exception.

Consequently you need to change your aspect like this (ignoring issues like multi-threading and nested exceptions created by manual try-catch etc. so as not to make it even more complicated):

**Aspect, iteration 2:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity;
import android.util.Log;

@Aspect
public class ExceptionHandlingAspect {
  private static final String TAG = ExceptionHandlingAspect.class.getName();

  private Set<Throwable> ignoredErrors = new HashSet<>();

  @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && target(activity)")
  public void methodsOfInterest(AspectActivity activity) {}

  @Pointcut("@annotation(android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.exception.NoTryCatch)")
  public void annotationNoTryCatch() {}

  @Around("methodsOfInterest(activity) && !annotationNoTryCatch()")
  public Object exceptionAroundMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, AspectActivity activity) throws Throwable {
    try {
      return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
      if (ignoredErrors.contains(throwable))
        throw throwable;
      String errorMessage = "Error " + throwable + " in method " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
      Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
      Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
      if (throwable instanceof AuthenticationException)
        builder.setTitle("Authentication Error").setMessage("You are not authenticated").show();
      else
        builder.setTitle("Error").setMessage(errorMessage).show();
      return null;
    }
  }

  @AfterThrowing(value = "methodsOfInterest(activity) && annotationNoTryCatch()", throwing = "throwable")
  public void ignoreExceptions(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, AspectActivity activity, Throwable throwable) {
    ignoredErrors.add(throwable);
  }
}
```

**Console log, iteration 2:**

```
Doing something
Doing something else
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: oops
    at android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.doSomethingElse(AspectActivity.java:17)
    at android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.run_aroundBody4(AspectActivity.java:27)
    at android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.run_aroundBody5$advice(AspectActivity.java:34)
    at android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.run(AspectActivity.java:1)
    at android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.main(AspectActivity.java:32)
```

As you can see, the exception now escalates, "crashing" the application as you said you wanted it to.

P.S.: `InheritableThreadLocal<Throwable>` is your friend if you like the aspect to be thread-safe. Feel free to ask about it if you do need that but don't know what I am talking about.

P.P.S.: If you move the `@NoTryCatch` annotation from `doSomethingElse()` down to `doSomethingFancy`, the log changes as follows:

```
Doing something
Doing something else
[de.scrum_master.aspect.ExceptionHandlingAspect] Error java.lang.RuntimeException: oops in method String android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.doSomethingElse()
ALERT DIALOG: Error -> Error java.lang.RuntimeException: oops in method String android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.doSomethingElse()
Doing something fancy
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException: uh-oh
    at android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.doSomethingFancy(AspectActivity.java:22)
    at android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.run_aroundBody4(AspectActivity.java:28)
    at android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.run_aroundBody5$advice(AspectActivity.java:34)
    at android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.run(AspectActivity.java:1)
    at android.mobile.peakgames.net.aspectjandroid.AspectActivity.main(AspectActivity.java:32)
```

Comment: ok. let say I annotated a method `test()`with `NoTryCatch` now it throws exception. The app must crash. `exceptionMethod ` should not handle the exception.

Comment: See extensive update. But as I said: Maybe you should not do that, I do not like this kind of application design.